# Automatic Weights Rigging makes model warp horribly on posing

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, parent

I've used Automatic Weights for rigging humanoid models a lot of times and it worked more or less perfectly. But for this one model, any movement of bones just grabs most of the mesh and deforms it strangely instead of affecting the appropriate part, weight painting does little to help as it just makes every bone affect the rotation of the entire mesh.

I have no idea what's causing this, tried cleaning the mesh up as much as possible but to no avail. 
Redid the skeleton 3 separate times, and the results are always the same.

Update:
The problem seems to be that the bones only deform the mesh, and don't move it at all otherwise. If deform is disabled, bones cease to have any effect on the mesh.
[image]

[image: Deformed]
[image: Moving a Bone]
[image: Rest Position]

Comment: upload your .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: its a weight paint issue, one of the bones had too much influence.[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5600" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5600/)

Comment: Thank's a lot ! Though it still does a similar thing, I've tried altering the weight painting, even substracting all of it completely, and it still bugs out, as if every bone was affecting every part of the mesh, unlike when applying it to any other model I've tried. Essentially it looks as if it was only deforming the mesh without moving if that makes any sense.

To demonstrate, this is what it looks like when trying to move a bone with and without deform on respectively 
https://i.imgur.com/11A7z6l.png
https://i.imgur.com/jhlujfz.png

Comment: Essentially, if I turn off deform of all the bones, the mech doesn't move at all with the movement of bones. Just tested it.